# text in div appears in correct place but its design elements don't

Tags: html, css, position

I am an amateur web developer and I'm trying to design an extremely basic div-based web layout; I can't figure out why the divs don't appear correctly. I have the following css:

```
body {
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0px auto;
}

/*Div all the way at the top */
#header {
    background-color: #0CF;
    height: 130px;
    position:relative;
}

/*Inner div contained by the header */
#sitemenu {
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #C9C;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}

/*Div appearing directly below the header */
#scheduleContainer {
    background-color: #FF9;
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

/*Div contained by "scheduleContainer", aligned left */
#schedule {
    background-color: #6C6;
    float: left;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
}

/*Div contained by "scheduleContainer", aligned right */
#scheduleInfo {
    background-color: #F69;
    float: right;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}

/*Appears directly below schedule container */
#content {
    background-color: #09F;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
```

And the following HTML which utilizes those styles in what I perceive to be a fairly straightforward manner:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
  <div id="sitemenu">Content for  sitemenu</div>

</div>
<div id="scheduleContainer">
  <div id="schedule">Content for  schedule Goes Here</div>
  <div id="scheduleInfo">Content for  id scheduleInfo Goes Here</div>
</div>

<div id="content">Content for  content</div>

</body>
```

The colors of the divs just helps me visualize the layout and the id names don't really mean anything yet. I just want to know why, on my browser, the text for the "content" div appears where I intend it to but the blue area that would be its background appears directly on top of the preceding div, as if the code for the content div is within that div (which it isn't, it comes directly after the closing tag for that div). All I want is to have the header, scheduleContainer, and content divs appear in the order they're written in the code. Feel free to criticize my decisions or recommend a different approach all together. I am very amateur and just want to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed some of the un-needed position:relative and clearedthe content div

```css
body {
   width: 1000px;
   margin: 0px auto;
}

/*Div all the way at the top */
#header {
    background-color: #0CF;
    height: 130px;
    position:relative;
}

/*Inner div contained by the header */
#sitemenu {
    height: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #C9C;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}

/*Div appearing directly below the header */
#scheduleContainer {
    background-color: #FF9;
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

/*Div contained by "scheduleContainer", aligned left */
#schedule {
    background-color: #6C6;
    float: left;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
}

/*Div contained by "scheduleContainer", aligned right */
#scheduleInfo {
    background-color: #F69;
    float: right;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}

/*Appears directly below schedule container */
#content {
    background-color: #09F;
    height:200px;
    clear:both
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
  <div id="sitemenu">Content for  sitemenu</div>

</div>
<div id="scheduleContainer">
  <div id="schedule">Content for  schedule Goes Here</div>
  <div id="scheduleInfo">Content for  id scheduleInfo Goes Here</div>
</div>

<div id="content">Content for  content</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your divs above it were floating. One common way is you can put a `clear:both` between the floats and your content div like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw9cmnah/)

```
  ....
  <div id="scheduleInfo">Content for  id scheduleInfo Goes Here</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="content">Content for  content</div>
```

[More information on clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

> A common problem with float-based layouts is that the floats'
>   container doesn't want to stretch up to accomodate the floats.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float from scheduleContainer.

```
#scheduleContainer {
    background-color: #FF9;
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```